# Passing variables between functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables, collections

I have this code:

```
collection = (function() {

    function collection(removeLinkTitle){

        this.removeLinkTitle = removeLinkTitle || 'delete';
    }

    collection.prototype = {

        removeLinkTitle:        this.removeLinkTitle,

        init:function(){

            ...some code...
            this.deleteCollectionForm();
        },

        deleteCollectionForm:function(){

        var removeFormA = $('<a href="#">'+this.removeLinkTitle+'</a>');
        linkLi.append( removeFormA );

        removeFormA.on('click', function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            linkLi.remove();

            var index = collectionHolder.data( 'index' );
            collectionHolder.data( 'index', index - 1 );
        });
    }
};

return collection;

})();
```

The thing is that the var removeForm returns its value only the frst time it loads, the following times it returns undefined.

I don't want to pass the variable as an argument so, is it there any other way to do this?

Thanks !!

Comment: How are you calling it ?

Comment: Why do you declare a `var` when the function ends in the next line?

Comment: really hard to tell something like this, i dont see where or when removeForm return something..?

Comment: you could make removeForm global by defining `var removeForm` outside functions. Then (removing the word `var` inside the function), the value assigned to it will be available.

Comment: @reyaner I am using it with an onclick event, like this             removeForm.on('click', function(e) {
                linkLi.remove();});

Answer (score 0):

i think this is not really the problem, the one thing that is undefined is the, removeLinkTitle, try this:

```
return new collection;
```

so you hit your constructor, or set some other value with:

```
return new collection("delete item");
```